# I still see unmerged classes when I am pointing on a branch without pushing in it in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have a weird problem, I guess it is eclipse problem but I am not sure, I created many classes in my spring boot project but I discarded all changes, I moved to develop branch and opened eclipse again and still see those classes that are causing problems when I try to build, example :

[image]

Class Item is a class I created but never pushed it, I did not push it even in my own branch, so what's up ? what is the problem ? is it eclipse problem ? The more important is how to fix the problem ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That file might not be tracked by git?

Comment: Git does not touch untracked files (if not instructed to) - check its History (Right click on File -> Team ->  Show in History). Using GIT (command line) you can use the `git clean` command to remove **all** untracked files, or, in Eclipse, use the Team->Synchronize Workspace view to show all differences and delete unwanted files.

Comment: Okay Thank you, this was the problem